# How to set my form icon off if the form is maximized with IsMdiContainer = true

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

How to set my form icon off when the child form is maximized into its parent form. I have set my IsMdiContainer = true. I just wanted to get the icon off coz it messes up my menu bar.

minimized :

[image: minimized version]

maximized :

[image: maximized version]

Sorry, i'm still new in c# winforms. Thanks for helping me out .. :)

Comment: I guess you would be stuck with this forever **unless** you have some workaround, sorry.

Comment: @KingKing i tried `controlbox = false` then i just double clicked the form it went maximized. But now i dont see the controlbox lol.. The icon is not visible now..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MenuStrip` is adding a menu for you.  You can stop it with this code:

```
private void menuStrip1_ItemAdded(object sender, ToolStripItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e != null && e.Item != null && e.Item.GetType().Name == "SystemMenuItem")
    {
        this.menuStrip1.Items.RemoveAt(0);
    }
}
```

Here's my full working example:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public class ExampleForm : Form
    {
        private System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip menuStrip1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem fileToolStripMenuItem;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem openToolStripMenuItem;

        public ExampleForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.menuStrip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip();
            this.fileToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.openToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.menuStrip1.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // menuStrip1
            // 
            this.menuStrip1.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
            this.fileToolStripMenuItem});
            this.menuStrip1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.menuStrip1.Name = "menuStrip1";
            this.menuStrip1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1002, 24);
            this.menuStrip1.TabIndex = 1;
            this.menuStrip1.Text = "menuStrip1";
            this.menuStrip1.ItemAdded += new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemEventHandler(this.menuStrip1_ItemAdded);
            // 
            // fileToolStripMenuItem
            // 
            this.fileToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
            this.openToolStripMenuItem});
            this.fileToolStripMenuItem.Name = "fileToolStripMenuItem";
            this.fileToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(37, 20);
            this.fileToolStripMenuItem.Text = "&File";
            // 
            // openToolStripMenuItem
            // 
            this.openToolStripMenuItem.Name = "openToolStripMenuItem";
            this.openToolStripMenuItem.ShortcutKeys = ((System.Windows.Forms.Keys)((System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Control | System.Windows.Forms.Keys.O)));
            this.openToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(146, 22);
            this.openToolStripMenuItem.Text = "&Open";
            this.openToolStripMenuItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.openToolStripMenuItem_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1002, 674);
            this.Controls.Add(this.menuStrip1);
            this.IsMdiContainer = true;
            this.MainMenuStrip = this.menuStrip1;
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.menuStrip1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.menuStrip1.PerformLayout();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var form = new Form
            {
                Text = "Child",
                MdiParent = this,
                ShowIcon = false
            };
            form.Show();
        }

        private void menuStrip1_ItemAdded(object sender, ToolStripItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e != null && e.Item != null && e.Item.GetType().Name == "SystemMenuItem")
            {
                this.menuStrip1.Items.RemoveAt(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @LyndonBrozTonelete yes, and this is of course a beautiful workaround, my last comment is still true, although it may not be impossible.

Comment: i finished up my system already, it is being used by my school now. But im just doing another voting system exercise.. then I bumped into this problem.. well you're right of course, @KingKing